# Remove selected attribute and add a new one on select element

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the following:

**HTML**

```
<select class="dropDownList" id="PersonFunction">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Vice President</option>
    <option value="2">Director</option>
    <option value="3">Secretary</option>
    <option value="4">Clerk</option>
</select>​
```

**JS**

```
$("#PersonFunction").change(function () {    
    $("option", this).eq($(this).val()).attr('selected', 'selected');
});​
```

So after the index change i set the selected attribute and it works but after the user changes the index again i set yet another selected attribute on different value and i don't want that.

```
<select class="dropDownList" id="PersonFunction">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Vice President</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Director</option>
    <option value="3">Secretary</option>
    <option value="4">Clerk</option>
</select>
```

How can i first remove selected attribute if one exists then add one?

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrcic/HCrS2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('#PersonFunction').on('change', function() {
  $('option:selected', this).attr('selected',true).siblings().removeAttr('selected');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HCrS2/6/)

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to update the `selected` attribute programmatically as the browser will automatically know which element is selected. The `selected` attribute is only intended to set a default option on page load.

To get the current selected option, just use the following:

```
var selectedValue = $("#PersonFunction option:selected").val();
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GbKmc/)

---

**Update**

If for whatever reason you do want to set a `selected` attribute (as form what I can understand you are creating another form dynamically), try this:

```
$("#PersonFunction").change(function () {   
    $("option", $(this)).removeAttr("selected");
    $("option:selected", $(this)).attr("selected", true);
});​
```

Comment: Because after user clicks on the submit i store div (where all my fields are) in form that is created dynamically and i don't have a selected attribute so the post doesn't work. I know how to get the value and didn't ask for that.

Comment: Ok, see my update - although I still don't fully understand the logic you're using to require this.

Comment: You may want to post your whole code, including the dynamic form creation and post, in another question as I don't think this is the best way to achieve what you need. Without more detail it's hard to say though.

Comment: Your update doesn't work as i tried this already, it always selects default value Choose.

Answer (score -1):

This will alert you the text thats selected. change .text() to .val() if you want it to pick up the option values instead

```
$("#PersonFunction").change(function () {
    var selected = $("option:selected").text();
    alert(selected);
});
```